# Setting up API POST Request Confusion

Tags: api, rest, postman

I'm setting up a POST request to an API. The service which has the API i'm integrating with is only giving me the following information:

HTTP Method: POST
API URL: https://websiteservice.com/api/v2
API Key: My API Key
Response format: JSON

Then it has two parameters:
key --> My API Key
action --> services

So I set it up in postman, and got an 200 response, but the correct return json data did not get returned.

How should I be setting this up in postman properly?

Comment: The API should have a documentation. If it is not documented, then ask the API developers.

Comment: What did you include in the request body? If the request is proper, then the api isn't working as per the requirements. Try once again with a request header "'accept: application/json' \"; if the response is still the same, contact the devs